# Change orientation of Word single page

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

Is there a way to change the orientation of single page using win32com?
I need to add a table and change orientation to landscape for only used page, not for full document. In Word application there is an option in "Page Setup" to change only selection:

[image: Text]

But I found nothing in terms of win32com.
I tried:

```
table.Range.PageSetup.Orientation = client.constants.wdOrientLandscape
word_app.Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = client.constants.wdOrientLandscape
```

But it rotates the whole document. Is there any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't a way in which you can use both portrait and landscape orientation in one same document. All you can do is  just paste the table sideways. So when you print it, it should be in portrait.

Comment: But I can do it using Word GUI, with the option mentioned on the image. That's too strange if I can't do it via code.